# MS Excel "grouping" functionality broken - NOT due to "Advanced" options or protected sheet or grouped sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have a strange problem: In a relatively wide spreadsheet (285 columns) my grouping functionality broke after I moved columns around using Shift and drag.

This obviously completely destroys usability, which was fine when grouping worked (there are lots of "helper) columns to prepare analyses which are fed into pivots etc.

In the "advanced" options, the tick to show outline symbols is applied. The sheet is not protected or anything.

What on earth is going on? And more importantly, how do I fix it? Restarting Excel and even rebooting does nothing.

Excel Version 2102

Comment: Without any data or concrete examples it is very difficult to give any guideance.

Comment: As per above it is hard to make suggestions without more details.    This is a bit of along shot, but you might have added blank data etc. to your schedule. You could try adding a row at the beginning of your worksheet and use COUNTA() like COUNTA(A2:A.100) or higher if there are more rows. Then use this to look for decencies in your data.

Comment: You should provide a sample here.